# Не работает открытие сетевого порта Windows

Tags: сервер, windows-10, wifi, port

Пытаюсь открыть порт, для примера, *43286* на роутере Kinetic Giga.

- Проброс портов в роутере, компьютер на выходе точно мой, я проверял `:)`

[image: Проброс портов в роутере]

Если я правильно понял, когда у требуемого сервиса [здесь](https://portforward.com/ports.htm) указаны порты и для TCP, и для UDP - я могу выбрать любой протокол и открывать соответствующий порт?

- Далее - брандмауэр.

Входное соединение:
[image: вход0]
[image: вход1]

Выходное соединение:
[image: выход0]
[image: выход1]

- Теперь антивирус:
  [image: антивирус0]
  [image: антивирус1]

Межсетевой экран не трогал, т.к. на сайте https://help.keenetic.com/hc/ru/articles/360000360760 (вроде как для моего роутера) написано:

> Важно! Дополнительную настройку межсетевого экрана производить не нужно, т.к. при использовании правила переадресации интернет-центр самостоятельно открывает доступ по указанному порту.

---

Потом я запускаю сервер на порту *43286* с IP = `localhost`, захожу на сайт https://myopenports.com/, проверяю этот порт и... он закрыт! (сайт определяет верно, т.к. к серверу невозможно подключиться).

Что я сделал не так?

P.S. сервер является `jar` файлом, так что могут быть некоторые проблемы. Например, брандмауэр предлагает добавить сетевое правило только для `exe` файлов. (и создал сервер не я, так что кода не будет)

---

**UPD**
Огромный *facepalm* мне...
Я не правильно указал вход для трафика... Я указывал провайдер, а нужно было PPPoE `:)`

---

**Проблема решена.**

Comment: Если IP=localhost, то внешние интерфейсы (сетевая карта) конечно будут проигнорированы и порт естественно будет закрыт. Задавайте IP=0.0.0.0 или что-то подобное

Comment: @andreymal теперь я изменил вход для трафика, и `localhost` не работает, а `0.0.0.0` работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю будет ли тебе полезна моя информация, но как открывал порт я. На роутере есть  такая штука, называется ДМЗ. Это означает открытие всех портов. Когда работал в технической поддержке одной компании (называть не буду название), сказали, что так делать надо всегда, потому что на некоторых роутерах не работает проброс 1 порта. [image: Пример DMZ]

Что касается остального, брандмауэр у меня выключен и антивирус тоже нету. После перезагрузки роутера порт открылся. Попробуй действовать методом исключения. Выключи всё, брандмауэр и антивирус. Сделай дмз, если сработало, включай по 1 элементу, то есть включи антивирус проверь, включи брэндмауэр проверь и т.д.